# Refactoring long class to make it more maintainable

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app. Due to my low experience and the requirement for network operation, my class uses a lot of `AsyncTask` instances and it grew quite large. I'd like to know how I can split this in to different classes, and generally make it better (not required).

I am really confused in cases where I have to deal with UI elemnts.

I wish to see some small code snippets which will demonstrate good practice. I am not asking for a full and really detailed answer, as it probably will be very long, but it would be really nice.

(Should I add some comments?)

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.adapter.GPSTracker;
import ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.adapter.JSONParser;
import ua.mirkvartir.android.frontend.adapter.UserFunctions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class AddFillActivityApp extends ErrorActivity

{
    Uri mCapturedImageURI;
    int gSelected;
    List<String> photos;
    int sourse = 3;
    String user_id;
    int dSelected;
    // File f;
    String filePath;
    int stSelected;
    int sSelected;
    int rSelected;
    EditText street;
    EditText price;
    Spinner spinPriceType;
    EditText flat;
    EditText sqTotal;
    EditText sqLiving;
    EditText sqKitchen;
    EditText floor;
    EditText floors;
    EditText text;
    EditText phone1;
    EditText phone2;
    Spinner spinBuildType;
    Button btnSend;
    Context context;
    String not_sourse = "";
    String not_user = "";
    String not_district = "";
    String not_settle = "";
    String not_section = "";
    String not_street = "";
    String not_price = "";
    String not_priceFor = "";
    String not_flat = "";
    String not_sqTotal = "";
    String not_sqLiving = "";
    String not_sqKitchen = "";
    String not_floor = "";
    String not_floors = "";
    String not_text = "";
    String not_phone1 = "";
    String not_phone2 = "";
    String not_build_type = "";
    String photo1 = "";
    String photo2 = "";
    String photo3 = "";
    ImageView pho1;
    ImageView pho2;
    ImageView pho3;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    List<Integer> priceID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> buildTypeID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> priceField = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> buildTypeField = new ArrayList<String>();
    Activity app;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBuild;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterPrice;
    String not_coord = "";
    Uri link1 = null;
    Uri link2 = null;
    Uri link3 = null;

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("link1")) {
            link1 = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("link1"));
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("link2")) {
            link2 = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("link2"));
        }
        if (savedInstanceState.containsKey("link3")) {
            link3 = Uri.parse(savedInstanceState.getString("link3"));
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d("links", link1 + "\n" + link2 + "\n" + link3);
        if (link1 != null && !link1.equals("")) {

            saveFile(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getRealPathFromURI(link1),
                            800, 800), 1);
            pho1.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    getRealPathFromURI(link1), 80, 60));
        }
        if (link2 != null && !link2.equals("")) {
            saveFile(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getRealPathFromURI(link2),
                            800, 800), 2);
            pho2.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    getRealPathFromURI(link2), 80, 60));
        }
        if (link3 != null && !link3.equals("")) {
            saveFile(
                    decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getRealPathFromURI(link3),
                            800, 800), 3);
            pho3.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    getRealPathFromURI(link3), 80, 60));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        app = this;
        context = this;
        pds.setTitle("Загружаются фото...");
        setContentView(R.layout.aadd_advappartment);
        pho1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto1);
        pho2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto2);
        pho3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagePhoto3);
        Button f1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto1);
        Button f2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto2);
        Button f3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPhoto3);
        ImageView back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        f1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                addPhoto1();
            }
        });
        f2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                addPhoto2();
            }
        });
        f3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                addPhoto3();
            }
        });
        back_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                delDir();
                finish();
            }
        });
        Bundle ex = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (ex != null) {
            btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendAdd);
            gSelected = ex.getInt("Group");
            sSelected = ex.getInt("Section");
            dSelected = ex.getInt("District");
            stSelected = ex.getInt("Settle");
            rSelected = ex.getInt("Region");
            user_id = ex.getString("user_id");
            RelativeLayout lp = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutPark);
            RelativeLayout la = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutApp);
            not_sourse = "" + 3;
            not_user = "" + user_id;
            not_district = "" + dSelected;
            not_settle = "" + stSelected;
            not_section = "" + sSelected;
            if (gSelected == 9) {
                lp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                la.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                spinPriceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sppricetipe);
                street = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpAdress);

                FillData dat = new FillData();
                dat.execute(1, gSelected, sSelected);

            } else {
                la.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                lp.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                spinPriceType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.saPricetipe);
                spinBuildType = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.saBuildType);
                FillData dat = new FillData();
                dat.execute(1, gSelected, sSelected);

                adapterBuild = new ArrayAdapter<String>(app,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, buildTypeField);
                adapterBuild
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinBuildType.setAdapter(adapterBuild);

                dat = new FillData();
                dat.execute(0);

            }
            adapterPrice = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, priceField);
            adapterPrice
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinPriceType.setAdapter(adapterPrice);

            // Listening to Login Screen link
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (gSelected == 9) {
                        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpPrice);

                        flat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpCarSpace);

                        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpDescription);

                        not_street = street.getText().toString();
                        not_price = price.getText().toString();
                        not_flat = flat.getText().toString();
                        not_sqTotal = "";
                        not_sqLiving = "";
                        not_sqKitchen = "";
                        not_floor = "";
                        not_floors = "";
                        not_text = "";
                        not_phone1 = "";
                        not_phone2 = "";
                        not_build_type = "0";
                    } else {
                        street = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaAdress);
                        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaPrice);

                        flat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaCarSpace);
                        sqTotal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaArea1);
                        sqLiving = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaArea2);
                        sqKitchen = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaArea3);
                        floor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaFlor);
                        floors = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaHight);
                        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaDescription);

                        not_street = street.getText().toString();
                        not_price = price.getText().toString();

                        not_flat = flat.getText().toString();
                        not_sqTotal = sqTotal.getText().toString();
                        not_sqLiving = sqLiving.getText().toString();
                        not_sqKitchen = sqKitchen.getText().toString();
                        not_floor = floor.getText().toString();
                        not_floors = floors.getText().toString();
                        not_text = text.getText().toString();
                        not_phone1 = "0";
                        not_phone2 = "0";

                    }
                    Upload upload = new Upload();
                    upload.execute();

                }

            });
            spinPriceType
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View view, int position, long id) {

                            if (position > -1 && priceID != null) {
                                not_priceFor = priceID.get(position).toString();
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });
            if (gSelected != 9) {
                spinBuildType
                        .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                    View view, int position, long id) {

                                if (position > -1 && buildTypeID != null) {
                                    not_build_type = buildTypeID.get(position)
                                            .toString();
                                }

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }

    class FillData extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, JSONArray> {
        private int op = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Integer... option) {
            JSONArray json = null;
            UserFunctions u = new UserFunctions();
            op = option[0];
            if (option[0] == 0) {

                json = u.getBt();
            } else if (option[0] == 1) {
                String not_group = option[1].toString();
                String not_section = option[2].toString();
                json = u.getPriceType(not_group, not_section);

            }

            // send add

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.dismiss();
            if (result == null) {


                onCreateDialog(LOST_CONNECTION).show();
            } else if (op == 0) {
                if (result != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        String a = "0";
                        String b = "0";
                        try {
                            a = ((JSONObject) result.get(i)).getString("bt_id");
                            b = ((JSONObject) result.get(i))
                                    .getString("bt_name");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        buildTypeID.add(Integer.parseInt(a));
                        buildTypeField.add(b);

                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            adapterBuild.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

                }
            } else if (op == 1) {
                if (result != null) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        String a = "0";
                        String b = "0";
                        try {
                            a = ((JSONObject) result.get(i))
                                    .getString("pricefor_id");
                            b = ((JSONObject) result.get(i))
                                    .getString("pricefor_title");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        priceID.add(Integer.parseInt(a));
                        priceField.add(b);

                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            adapterPrice.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }
        }

    }

    class Upload extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pds.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONObject json1 = null;
            JSONParser u = new JSONParser();
            photos = new ArrayList<String>();
            photos.add(photo1);
            photos.add(photo2);
            photos.add(photo3);
            List<File> f = new ArrayList<File>();

            for (String p : photos) {
                Log.d("FilePath", p);
                if (!p.equals("") && !p.equals("empty")) {
                    f.add(new File(p));
                }
            }

            if (f.size() > 0) {
                json1 = u.getJSONFromUrl(f);
            } else {
                return null;
            }

            photos.clear();
            return json1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            JSONArray urls = null;

            SendData s;
            if (result != null && result.has("url")) {
                try {
                    urls = result.getJSONArray("url");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                photos.clear();
                if (urls != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < urls.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            photos.add(urls.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                    "photo_id"));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            s = new SendData();
            s.execute(not_sourse, not_user, not_district, not_settle,
                    not_section, not_street, not_price, not_priceFor, not_flat,
                    not_sqTotal, not_sqLiving, not_sqKitchen, not_floor,
                    not_floors, not_text, not_phone1, not_phone2,
                    not_build_type, "" + rSelected);
        }

    }

    class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd.setTitle("Создаю Объявление...");
            if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(context);
                        if (mGPS.canGetLocation) {

                            double mLat = mGPS.getLatitude();
                            double mLong = mGPS.getLongitude();
                            not_coord = "" + mLong + "," + mLat;

                        } else {
                            // can't get the location
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... option) {
            JSONObject json = null;
            UserFunctions u = new UserFunctions();
//          publishProgress(values);
            String not_sourse = option[0];
            String not_user = option[1];
            String not_district = option[2];
            String not_settle = option[3];
            String not_section = option[4];
            String not_street = option[5];
            String not_price = option[6];
            String not_priceFor = option[7];
            String not_flat = option[8];
            String not_sqTotal = option[9];
            String not_sqLiving = option[10];
            String not_sqKitchen = option[11];
            String not_floor = option[12];
            String not_floors = option[13];
            String not_text = option[14];
            String not_phone1 = option[15];
            String not_phone2 = option[16];
            String not_build_type = option[17];
            String not_region = option[18];

            json = u.sendAdd(not_sourse, not_user, not_district, not_settle,
                    not_section, not_street, not_price, not_priceFor, not_flat,
                    not_sqTotal, not_sqLiving, not_sqKitchen, not_floor,
                    not_floors, not_text, not_phone1, not_phone2,
                    not_build_type, not_region, photos, not_coord);

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.e("result", "going to result");

            String not_id = "0";
            pds.dismiss();
            if (result == null) {
                Log.e("result", "null");

                onCreateDialog(LOST_CONNECTION).show();
            } else {
                Log.e("result", "not null:" + result.toString());
                try {
                    if (result != null) {
                        not_id = result.getString("notice_id");
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                AddToCheckActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("add_id", not_id);
                        startActivity(i);
                        link1 = null;
                        link2 = null;
                        link3 = null;
                        delDir();

                        finish();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void addPhoto1() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Выберите первое фото")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("С диска",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // do things
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                link1 = null;
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
                                        intent, "Select Picture"), 11);
                                if (filePath != null) {

                                }
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Сфотографировать",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // do things
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                                        "zdanie " + c.getTime());
                                link1 = null;

                                link1 = getContentResolver()
                                        .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                                values);
                                Intent intentPicture = new Intent(
                                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                        link1);
                                startActivityForResult(intentPicture, 12);
                            }
                        });
        builder.create().show();

    }

    public void addPhoto2() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("Выберите второе фото")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("С диска",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // do things
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setType("image/*");
                                link2 = null;
                                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
                                        intent, "Select Picture"), 21);
                                if (filePath != null) {
                                    Log.d("Execution", "CCCCMON");

                                }
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Сфотографировать",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // do things
                                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,
                                        "zdanie " + c.getTime());
                                link2 = null;

                                link2 = getContentResolver()
                                        .insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                                values);
                                Intent intentPicture = new Intent(
                                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                        link2);
                                startActivityForResult(intentPicture, 22);
                            }
                        });
        builder.create().show();

    }



    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if (link1 != null) {
            outState.putString("link1", link1.toString());
        }
        if (link2 != null) {
            outState.putString("link2", link2.toString());
        }
        if (link3 != null) {
            outState.putString("link3", link3.toString());
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String a = "";
        if (data == null) {
            a = "null";
        } else
            a = data.toString();
        Log.d("RealPAth", "resultCode " + resultCode + " data " + a);
        if (requestCode == 12 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        }
        if (requestCode == 11 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            link1 = data.getData();
            String picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(link1);

            pho1.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(picturePath,
                    80, 60));
            saveFile(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(picturePath, 800, 800), 1);

        }
        if (requestCode == 22 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        }
        if (requestCode == 21 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            link2 = data.getData();
            String picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(link2);
            pho2.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(picturePath,
                    80, 60));
            saveFile(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(picturePath, 800, 800), 2);

        }
        if (requestCode == 32 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        }
        if (requestCode == 31 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            link3 = data.getData();

            String picturePath = getRealPathFromURI(link3);
            pho3.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(picturePath,
                    80, 60));

            saveFile(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(picturePath, 800, 800), 3);
        }
    }

    public String saveFile(Bitmap bm, int id) {
        if (bm == null) {
            Log.d("bitmap", "null");
            return "";
        } else {
            String file_path = getExternalCacheDir () + "/Mk";
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();

            }
            File file = new File(dir, "smaller" + id +bm.getHeight()+ ".jpeg");
            FileOutputStream fOut;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                // bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
                BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fOut);
                bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bos);
                if (bos != null) {
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                }
                if (fOut != null) {
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                }
                if (id == 1) {
                    photo1 = file.getPath();
                } else if (id == 2) {
                    photo2 = file.getPath();
                } else if (id == 3) {
                    photo3 = file.getPath();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }
    }

    public void photo1Clear(View v) {
        photo1 = "";
        link1 = null;
        pho1.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
    }

    public void photo2Clear(View v) {
        photo2 = "";
        link2 = null;

        pho2.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
    }

    public void photo3Clear(View v) {
        photo3 = "";
        link3 = null;

        pho3.setImageResource(R.drawable.home);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        if (contentUri == null) {
            Log.e("RealPath", "URI: null");

        } else
            Log.e("RealPath", "URI: " + contentUri.toString());
        try {

            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(app, contentUri, proj, null,
                    null, null);
            Cursor cursor = loader.loadInBackground();
            int column_index = cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("RealPath", "exeption" + " " + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;


        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and
            // width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                    / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
            // guarantee
            // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
            // requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
            Log.d("bitmap", "original options: height/reqheite " + height+"///"+reqHeight + " widnth/reqwidth "
                    + width +"///"+reqWidth + " inSampleSize " + inSampleSize);
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }


    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        Log.e("PATH", path);
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        Bitmap b = null;

        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        // Calculate inSampleSizeа
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

        try {
            b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
            Log.d("bitmap", "decoded sucsessfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("bitmap", "decoding failed; options: " + options.toString());
        }

        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us the important parts you want reviewed, do not simply copy-paste the entire class. You think someone would want to read 900 lines of your code? :) I seriously doubt it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A few tips, but there may be more. These are just the things that immediately jumped out at me:

---

> Break out AsyncTasks into their own class

With multiple tasks, it might be better to make them each their own class/file. You can call back to the main Activity with listeners. If you *must* keep them in place, at least group them together at the end of the file. There's no reason to have them right in the middle of another class, with methods on both sides.

---

> Combine the button listeners

Instead of making several anonymous listeners, you can let the Activity implement the listener and have all the corresponding code in one neat method. There, you switch on button id to call individual methods to handle each. This is a personal style issue, but I think it makes it *much* more readable to have one `onClick()` function.

---

> Combine the `addPhoto()` methods

The only difference I see between `addPhoto1()` and `addPhoto2()` is the request code. Combine them into one `addPhoto(int reqCode)` method. If you add more later, it will be *much* easier than copy/pasting a whole new method called `addPhoto7()`, etc.

---

> Learn to use `switch` more, or refactor those `if` blocks

Big `if/else` blocks are ugly, and can sometimes be rewritten with a single `switch`. Sometimes, you need a bit more. For instance, in your `onActivityResult()` method, you can easily check `resultCode` just once, with a switch inside that. Same with the `data == null` checks.